# ImageResizer CloudFlare Plugin on Windows Server and Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis-7, http-status-code-404, windows-server-2008-r2, imageresizer

I'm running image resizer and whondering, wheather there is an CloudFlare Plugin? I noticed, there is a CloudFront plugin, but we want to use CloudFlare.

Is there any plugin or can I create my own in a easy way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### There is no need for CDN-specific plugins

The CloudFront plugin was created back before Amazon supported query string pass-through. It allowed the semcolon syntax to be used instead (I.e, `;width=200;height=200` instead of `?width=200&height=200`.

Today, nearly all CDNs with origin-server support query string preservation (usually by configuration). The CloudFront plugin is no longer necessary unless you need to support the alternate syntax.

Comment: Oh..I just realized how CloudFlare works. http://www.quora.com/CloudFlare/How-does-CloudFlare-work I didn't have to do anything lol. Thank you Computer Linguist.